# Airflow REST API - task_instance_api- get_task_instances_batch - Invalid inputs given to generate an instance of 'TaskInstanceCollectionAllOf'

Tags: api, airflow

I am trying to pull data on all of my tasks from all of my dags in my airflow instance using the airflow REST API

after defining a healthy client connection I am defining a variable of the task instance api:

```
self.task_instance = task_instance_api.TaskInstanceApi(self.general_instance)
```

then I am using the following method to get the response from the api:

```
def get_tasks(self):
            list_task_instance_form = ListTaskInstanceForm()
            response=self.task_instance.get_task_instances_batch(list_task_instance_form)
            return response
```

but i get the following raise:

Invalid inputs given to generate an instance of 'TaskInstanceCollectionAllOf'. The input data was invalid for the allOf schema 'TaskInstanceCollectionAllOf' in the composed schema 'TaskInstanceCollection'. Error=Invalid type for variable 'trigger'. Required value type is Trigger and passed type was NoneType at ['received_data']['task_instances'][0]['trigger']

I looked carefully in the github source code:
[github client api source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow-client-python/blob/main/airflow_client/client/model/list_task_instance_form.py)

but i didnt found something that can cause it.
I will appreciate your assistance.